# How to display different data in Datagrid based on some criteria? C#

Tags: c#, database, datagridview

I am currently breaking my head over a school project where i have to simulate a smart-shopping bag (datagridview) where customers log in and put various products in it (fruit,chocolates, etc...) and buy them.

They cam insert product into the bag, change it or remove it.

The problem is that i am simulating it with DatagridView, where users see the products that other users selected to buy, since DataGrid only shows the table in the database as a whole. Is there any way to display the products that the specific UserID have put into the datagridview?

Comment: Use a filter on your datasource. How are you retrieving the data before binding it to the grid?

Comment: I actually just dragged one table from my DataSet , the Products table and put it into DataGridView with the automated tableadapter.

Comment: And the UserID is stored in session? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/59bfya48.aspx

Comment: There is no session since it is not an ASP application involving internet, it is a local one, demonstrating how the shopping works.

Comment: Point being, use the filter and don't just drag and drop entire table. If you have a local dataset, Google row filter. If you have a data source, use select command with where clause or filter expressions. When possible, delegate the query execution to where it belongs - the database. Don't just bring all the records in memory to select a few for display purposes.